# SSRS PDF Generation

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net

i convert to PDF from SSRS Reports and show that PDF for Printing, but when records changes in report, i will recreate PDF, but it is not reflected in PDf, but when i open in folder path, it is generated correctly! i use same name for report, in my case i ll recreate number of times, print button is clicked, the problem is the PDF overwritten timing delay, i want to solve this issue, please help me

Answer (score 0):

you should refresh using refresh button on the SSRS, without refresh using this button the data will not get refreshed